# Generic struct that can hold either Rc<RefCell<T>> or Arc<RwLock<T>>

Tags: generics, rust, smart-pointers, refcell

I'm struggling with the implementing a struct in Rust that is able to hold either `Rc<RefCell<T>>` or `Arc<RwLock<T>>`.

The motivation of such a design is to allow the user to use cheaper and faster `Rc<RefCell<T>>` when the code will run in a single thread and only go to `Arc<RwLock<T>>` when parallelization is needed.

That's what I'm doing now:

```
struct Structure {}

struct Sel<R,DR> 
where
    R: Deref<Target=DR>,
    DR: Borrow<Structure>,
{
    structure: R,
}

impl<R,DR> Sel<R,DR> 
where
    R: Deref<Target=DR>,
    DR: Borrow<Structure>,
{
    fn new(structure: R) -> Self {
        Self{structure}
    }
}

fn main() {
    let st = Rc::new(RefCell::new(Structure{}));
    let sel = Sel::new(st);
}
```

The structure Sel can hold any type R that dereferences to whatever type DR, which in turn implements Borrow (Structure is the user type to wrap). In theory both `Rc<RefCell<T>>` and `Arc<RwLock<T>>` should satisfy these trait bounds, but the compiler shouts at me:

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `RefCell<Structure>: Borrow<Structure>` is not satisfied
  --> src/main.rs:26:15
   |
26 |     let sel = Sel::new(st);
   |               ^^^^^^^^ the trait `Borrow<Structure>` is not implemented for `RefCell<Structure>`
```

What is the correct way of implementing this? Which trait bound I can use to express that DR could be used in place of &Structure?

Comment: Where do you see that `RefCell<T>` has a blanket impl of `Borrow<T>`? In the documentation, I can only see the blanket impl of `Borrow<T> for T`.

Comment: Same applies for `RwLock`, btw. To consolidate both `RefCell` and `RwLock` you'd need to create your own `Lock` trait.

Comment: @FilipeRodrigues you are right, it seems that borrow() in of RefCell is just a method and not an implementation of Borrow trait. Is there any trait, which is common for RefCell and RwLock that could be used as bound in my implementation?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of. I know the crate `lock_api` abstracts over different lock types, but it seems it doesn't consider `RefCell` as an `RwLock`-like, so you'd probably need to create your own trait and implement it for both of them.

Comment: I considered this already. Unfortunately I can't understand how to write such a trait. Return types RefCell::borrow() and RwLock::read() are dirrerent and I can't figure out how can I express this in a trait function:

trait Shared {
  fn read(&self) -> which-type-here?;
}

Comment: You can return [`Either<ReadGuard, Ref>`](https://docs.rs/either/1.9.0/either/enum.Either.html)

Comment: Or you can use an associated type that implements `Deref<Target = T>` and return that instead.

Comment: I'm not sure what the point of this all is. If you find a way to combine the two, they still differ in one very important way: `Arc<Mutex<>>` is `Sync`, `Rc<RefCell<>>` is not. So how would you use such a combination of those two in a real scenario? At some point you have to decide whether you need `Sync` or not, and then you have to go back to the original type, because the combined type most certainly won't be `Sync` if it has the capability of storing a `Rc<RefCell<>>`.

Comment: @Finomnis the idea is not the combined type but a generic, which holds either Arc or Rc. If I need Sync I'll create this generic type with Arc.

Comment: @FilipeRodrigues thanks a lot for pointing me to associated types! This seems to be a correct solution. At least it now works in the [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=ee0a633c67eb34a5ec3d6c43c9e4aafa)!

Comment: Interesting. I didn't know you could use lifetimes like this with associated types.

Comment: @Finomnis It's a relatively new feature: https://blog.rust-lang.org/2022/10/28/gats-stabilization.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some excellent hints in the comments I've found a solution, which appeared to be universal enough to justify creation of the crate for it.
I've called it [UniRcLock](https://crates.io/crates/uni_rc_lock).

It is based on the idea to define a common trait for `Rc<RefCell<T>>` and `Arc<RwLock<T>>`. The implementation requires some advanced trait magic with [generic associated types](https://blog.rust-lang.org/2022/10/28/gats-stabilization.html) that allows to handle the lifetimes and to express the behavior of scoped read and write access guards in a generic manner.

It could be used like this (copy-pasted from the [crate docs](https://docs.rs/uni_rc_lock/0.2.0/uni_rc_lock/)):

```rust
#[derive(Debug)]
struct Foo(i32);

fn incr_foo(v: impl UniRcLock<Foo>){
    v.write().0 += 1;
}

// Using Rc
let ptr1 = Rc::new(RefCell::new(Foo(0)));
incr_foo(ptr1.clone());
println!("After increment: {:?}", ptr1);

// Using Arc
let ptr2 = Arc::new(RwLock::new(Foo(0)));
incr_foo(ptr2.clone());
println!("After increment: {:?}", ptr2);
```

I hope it could be useful :)